# How to choose suitable segmentation process for image processing

Tags: image-segmentation, opencv, thresholding

Hello I'm new on image processing.

I know there are a lot of threshold and region growing algorithms to use.

But I would like to know what is the trick for choosing suitable method for an image ?

Currently I'm trying to extract characters from this image

[image]

and most of the methods I've tried didn't really satisfy me. So I thought maybe I am doing it wrong. Here are some samples.

Normal Threshold

[image]

Sobel

[image]

Adaptive Threshold

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thresholding techniques that you would find [here](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~shafait/papers/Shafait-efficient-binarization-SPIE08.pdf) should be ideally suited to OCR applications. You could read and easily implement. They are also very efficient.